# 2 grep calls with pipe doesn't work as expected

Tags: linux, grep, pipe

I came up with the following command: `grep 'rtl' reg_list.txt | grep -E -o -n "id_\w+" reg_list.txt`

The idea is that first grep lines which contains rtl content, then grep only the words which starts with id_ content. These data is in table, the first column contains rtl, the second column contains id_ data.

The problem is that, the result of first grep is not passed to the second one.

The reg_list.txt consists of different types of data, such as lines, tables with column and rows.

Answer (score 5):

The result of the first `grep` *is* passed to the second `grep`, but since you give the second `grep` a filename, it will not read it (it would read from the file instead).

Instead:

```
grep 'rtl' reg_list.txt | grep -E -o -n 'id_[[:alnum:]]+'
```

I've also changed `\w` to `[[:alnum:]]` since `\w` is a PCRE regular expression.  If your `grep` is GNU `grep`, you may keep `\w` and use `grep -P` instead.

Comment: a side question, is there a way to prioritize the pipe against the inputfile for a command?

Comment: @αғsнιη With `grep`, you can make it read _both_ by specifying `/dev/stdin` together with the name of a file (it will read from each in turn), but if you give it a filename, you can't have it ignore it.